# How to protect WinForms ConnectionString

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, app-config, securestring

How to protect connectionstring especially db password ? I've found some examples but it's hard to understand them.

Does anyone have actual code examples? Thanks.

EDIT: Protect against standard users. Basic protection for sa password in connectionString needed.

Comment: Protect against _who_, in what environment?

Comment: Anything your application can read, a user on the machine can also read.

Comment: Link the resources which you feel hard to understand.

Comment: Don't use your SA password to connect to SQL from an application?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible for you or not, but why not set it up to prompt the user for their username / password and feed it into the connection string at run-time?

Comment: Firstly you need to make it clear where you're having your dbpassword. Is it in Config file?

Comment: You can't protect the password from users and at the same time allow the application to read it. The best you can do is obscure it so that it is not easy to find. This might seem OK to you, but it depends on how sensitive the data is. My advice us don't rely on obscurity.

Answer (score 3):

If the application is to connect directly to the database, then you should regard that connection information as available to the user running the application. You might obfuscate it yes, but protect it entirely isn't possible.

You have two options for implementing security:

1. Make sure that there is proper security on the database level so that the user can only perform operations that are okay. That obviously means using another user than `sa`.
2. Don't access the DB directly from the application, but let the application call a service (a WCF service is simple to get started with) on a server and let that server perform access checks and connect to the database.

No 2. is the most common architectural solution.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which discusses encrypting configuraton information. The information in the article works with both a web.config file and an app.config file.

For an example of this, try looking at [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)